# Scala method priority

Tags: scala

Anyone knows why the compiler apply this kind of priority on method call?

```
object Wrap {

  case class Vertex(label: String) {
    def <--(label: String) = SemiEdge(this, label)
  }

  case class Edge(from: Vertex, to: Vertex, label: String)

  case class SemiEdge(from: Vertex, label: String) {
    def -->(to: Vertex) = Edge(from, to, label)
  }

  // This doesn’t work because the right function is applied first
  Vertex("paris") <-- "eurostar" --> Vertex("london")
  // This does work
  (Vertex("paris") <-- "eurostar") --> Vertex("london")
}
```

I know this is linked to the [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) but it looks like this is a bug in this case no?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The first character of your operator determines the precedence. So, **-** will happen before **<**.
From the [Scala Reference section 6.12.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> 6.12.3 Infix Operations
>   An infix operator can be an arbitrary identifier. Infix operators have precedence and
>   associativity defined as follows:
>   The precedence of an infix operator is determined by the operator’s first character. Characters are listed below in **increasing order of precedence**, with characters on the same line having the same precedence.
>   
> (all letters)
>   
> |
>   
> ^
>   
> &
>   
> < >
>   
> = !
>   
> :
>   
> + -
>   
> * / %
>   
> (all other special characters)

Answer (score 0):

Scala determines operator priority by the first symbol of the operator. First symbol of `<--` is `<`, first symbol of `-->` is `-`. `<` has lower priority than `-`, therefore `<--` also has lower priority than `-->`.